# How do other applications use my Trello account?

Tags: trello, account-management

What does "No applications are using your Trello account" mean under my account settings?

Answer (score 4):

Since Trello has a rather robust API, there is the possibility for you or others to build consumers (apps) of Trello that can read and write to your boards and cards. To use an outside serivice with Trello, you have to authorize that serivice and Trello will issue it an API token so that it can act on your behalf: reading, writing, etc, as authorized.

The account setting you are looking at is a way you can revoke that access should the need arise.